# Most efficient way to enforce uniqueness for varchar in large table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL DB that should contain around 50-100 million records.

My table fields are: `TABLE_ID (INT), TABLE_STRING (VARCHAR 255), TABLE_BOOL (INT)`

`TABLE_ID` is my primary key, but I need to make sure that `TABLE_STRING` is kept unique for all rows in the table.

Should I set `TABLE_STRING` as index and use my script to use a `SELECT` to check if the string already exist or should set `TABLE_STRING` as unique in my table settings?

Is there any other way of achieving this? If not which one of the above is better?

Thanks,

Comment: Something wrong with simply adding a unique key on the table_string field? Keys only get updated when you add/alter/delete records. Otherwise they're just some extra data that won't get used/touched.

Comment: @Marc B - that was one of the options I've mentioned above.. Is that the right way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have an issue with space, then you could easily add a UNIQUE index for the `TABLE_STRING` field.

This will create a unique index for that field which will alert you if you are trying to add duplicate data (insert/update operations).

Since you have a large volume of rows and the fact that the field is VARCHAR(255) expect the index file to be quite large.

If however you do have concerns about space, then you might want to drop the `TABLE_ID` and use the `TABLE_STRING` as your primary key (which will be unique).

I would personally just add the unique index on the `TABLE_STRING` field.

Please note that the operation of adding the index might initially fail if you already have rows that have duplicate content for that field. A good practice is to first check if there are any duplicate data in that field.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you should create a `UNIQUE` index on `TABLE_STRING`. You also should look into partitioning, as it will improve performance on the indexes by having local indexes in each partition.